# Our webapplication hosted on the ec2 instance is developed in CodeIgniter

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, session-cookies

However there has been inconsistencies in the ci_session table in the installed MySQL server. Some ip addresses are being inserted repeatedly. However when we login from our system, those ipaddresses are not logged/inserted into the ci_session table. Does this mean that only certain ipaddresses are inserted in the ci_session table?

Can you able to provide guidance on this?

```
PHP version :7.2.15

MySQL version:  5.0.12

Codeigniter version : 3.1.3

Using session library : default system session library

Server : aws
```

Comment: what CI version are you using? what's your session's config? Also what is the essential code (where you add/retrieve the session values).  Please add/update that into your question.

Comment: I'd update to CI 3.1.10 (current release), there were some bugs involving the session library resolved, see: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html

Comment: what you are describing in your question could be resolved since 3.1.6: *Updated the Session Library ‘redis’, ‘memcached’ drivers to reduce the potential of a **locking race conditions**.*

Comment: Ok.I will try and let you know. Thanks a lot
 @Vickel

Comment: did the update help?

Comment: How to update session library ? @Vickel

Comment: you better upgrade the whole CI installation: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrading.html